# Not Receiving Push Notifications

Tags: iphone, push-notification

previously i had configured my app id for development push notifications it was working fine.

But now i have changed my appid and i have followed the same procedure as stated in the apple docs and i have put newly generated .p12 file on the server side but i am not getting the push to my device now.

i have a doubt for an apple id i generate both development and production ssl certificates and in programme portal both environments shows green balls.

i have created development provision profile after doing as said above. in the sever side do i need to point to production ssl or development ssl for testing.

can anybody have any idea about this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends which server are you contacting.

If you are testing on the development side, you have to send requests to the sandbox (gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com) using the appropriate SSL certificate and the appropriated Device Token.

If you are on production/release mode, you have to use the correspondent info.

Another thing that you have to keep in mind is that, for each certificate you have to register your device for push notifications, and if you change the provisioning profile, you have to do everything again, because the Device Token will be different.

Cheers,
VFN

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the device which you are testing doesn't have both the development profile and the distribution profile. Only distribution (adhoc) profile must be there.